# How to populate 2D array with char array in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to fill a 2D char array with characters form a char array

I have tried this code but not finding the problem

```
    public void FillArray(char[,] array, char[] values)
    {
      
        for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < values.Length; k++)
                {
                    array[i, j] = values[k];
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the problem with it?

Comment: is looping array more times and not filling array in right way, i think problem is to this nested for loops

Comment: I think you need to describe what you're trying to get out of this. What does "filling array in right way" mean? The most inner loop is iterating over the `values` for each `i`/`j` pair; is that what you're wanting?

Comment: Could you please provide the exception or the problem you have and what have you tried

Comment: Show how you're calling it. Are you passing it an empty array?

Comment: char[,] mainArray = new char[6, 6]; 
            char[] CharArray = new char[4] { 'a', 'b','c','d' };
            operations.FillArray(mainArray,CharArray);

Comment: this is filling 2d array with only last char 'd'

Comment: @FiboDeveloper, your code sets each cell in the 2d array first to a, then to b, then to c, then to d.  That's what the inner loop with k does.  What are you trying to do instead?

Comment: @adv12 I need one char to be in one index on 2d array like :   char[] charArray = new char[] {'a','b','c','d'};  and 2d array char[,] mainArray = new char[6,6];   i need each of chars to be in order indexes of 2d array like: 'a' in main[0,0] , 'b' in main[0,1] etc

Comment: Look at what your code is doing [in the debugger](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/). Then put the values of `array` and `values` [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71945636/edit).

Answer (score 1):

Your first for loop is responsible for iteration over first dimension of array `(i)` It's okay.
Your second for loop is responsible for iteration over second dimension of array `(j)`. It's okay.
Your third loop is responsible for  iteration over char values array `(k)` Here's your bug.

For a given set of values of `i` and `j` which represents dimensions indexes of array, your function iterates through all positions of `values` array. **So for each `k` value `i` and `j` values remain unchanged**. Therefore you sequentially put all the values of `values` array (k+1)times into the same cell of two dimension array, ultimately leaving it with value of `values[values.Length]` as it is the highest possible value of `k` in the most nested loop.

I'd suggest solution similar to what @adv12 has proposed with slight modification as I am not sure if the `k` value would be 0 during first iteration of the nested for loop. It is also more readable IMO.

```
int k = 0;
public void FillArray(char[,] array, char[] values)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            array[i, j] = values[k];
            k++
            if (k >= values.Length)
            {
                k = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would also like to point out that this bug could have been spotted easily if you had debugged it with breakpoints. You would have simply observed how i, j and k values change with each iteration and at some point it would be perfectly clear where the bug is. If you are not familiar with breakpoints I'd suggest that you watch a video tutorial. There are many tutorials on youtube covering this subject and this is essential programming knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my best guess at what you want based on your comments:

```
int k = 0;
public void FillArray(char[,] array, char[] values)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            array[i, j] = values[k++];
            if (k >= values.Length)
            {
                k = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```